# How to "subtract" string appearing in one dataframe column from the end of another string in a different column

Tags: r, string, dataframe, data.table, stringr

In a data frame with two character columns, how can I "subtract" a string that appears in one column from the *end* of a string that appears in the other column?

### Example

Here's some toy data:

```r
library(tibble)

my_df <-
  tribble(~full_string,    ~substring_to_remove,
          "dogz",          "z",
          "catap",         "ap",
          "tigera",        "a",
          "mouseppt",      "ppt",
          "kangaroolllyt", "lllyt",
          "qlionq",         "q",
          "zebra",          "z")

my_df
#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#>   full_string   substring_to_remove
#>   <chr>         <chr>              
#> 1 dogz          z                  
#> 2 catap         ap                 
#> 3 tigera        a                  
#> 4 mouseppt      ppt                
#> 5 kangaroolllyt lllyt              
#> 6 qlionq        q                  
#> 7 zebra         z
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

### Desired output

I want to create another column `clean_string`, that will "subtract" the string in `substring_to_remove` from the *end* of `full_string`.

```r
## # A tibble: 7 x 3
##   full_string   substring_to_remove clean_string
##   <chr>         <chr>               <chr>       
## 1 dogz          z                   dog         
## 2 catap         ap                  cat         
## 3 tigera        a                   tiger       
## 4 mouseppt      ppt                 mouse       
## 5 kangaroolllyt lllyt               kangaroo    
## 6 qlionq        q                   qlion       
## 7 zebra         z                   zebra
```

---

**EDIT**

---

If this is not too greedy to ask, it would be very helpful to also have a `data.table` solution to this problem, since this operation is quite time-consuming with large datasets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
library(tidyverse)
my_df <- my_df %>% 
  mutate(cleans_string = str_remove(full_string, paste0(substring_to_remove,"$")))
```

Output:

```
  full_string   substring_to_remove cleans_string
  <chr>         <chr>               <chr>       
1 dogz          z                   dog         
2 catap         ap                  cat         
3 tigera        a                   tiger       
4 mouseppt      ppt                 mouse       
5 kangaroolllyt lllyt               kangaroo    
6 qlionq        q                   qlion       
7 zebra         z                   zebra
```

Comment: That's neat, thanks! Could you explain the mechanism? What's the deal with the `$`?

Comment: The  `$` is a way in `stringr` package to tell you want the pattern check to be at the end of a string. For instance, `pattern = "a$"` in a `stringr` function will check for this pattern at the end of a string while `pattern = "a"` will look for an `a` in the entire string.

Answer (score 3):

data.table version

```r
setDT(my_df)[,clean_string:=stringr::str_remove(full_string, paste0(substring_to_remove, "$"))]
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using `endsWith` with `substr`.

```
my_df$clean_string <- substr(my_df$full_string, 1, nchar(my_df$full_string) -
         endsWith(my_df$full_string, my_df$substring_to_remove) *
            nchar(my_df$substring_to_remove))

my_df
## A tibble: 7 x 3
#  full_string   substring_to_remove clean_string
#  <chr>         <chr>               <chr>       
#1 dogz          z                   dog         
#2 catap         ap                  cat         
#3 tigera        a                   tiger       
#4 mouseppt      ppt                 mouse       
#5 kangaroolllyt lllyt               kangaroo    
#6 qlionq        q                   qlion       
#7 zebra         z                   zebra
```

or using `sub`:

```
my_df$clean_string <- mapply(sub, paste0(my_df$substring_to_remove, "$"), ""
                           , my_df$full_string)
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you help showing how to translate these to end up with dataframe format?

Comment: Yes. Please see update. Just adding `my_df$clean_string <- ` in front.